# NgModel is printing wrong values of my input

Tags: angular, typescript

I have one `*ngFor` inside other `*ngFor`. The input is showing the wrong values. I think it's because the name that I put is wrong

I try something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let produto of produtosConfirmadosAnuncio; let r = index">

    <div *ngFor="let variacao of produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.variacao; let m = index">
        <p><strong>Variação {{m+1}}</strong></p>
        <div>
            <div *ngFor="let atributosvariacao of produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.variacao.atributo">
                <p><strong>{{atributosvariacao.valor_atributo.item_atributo.item}}</strong></p>
                <p>{{atributosvariacao.valor_atributo.valor}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngFor="let variacao of produto.variacao; let j = index">
        <p><strong>Valor da variação {{j+1}} *</strong></p>
        <input name="valorvariacao{{j}}" required [(ngModel)]="variacao.preco_variacao" type="text">
        <h6 *ngIf="variacao.preco_variacao == null && submited"></h6>
    </div>
</div>
```

The input with name `valorvariacao{{j}}` is printing wrong values.

How is the correct index of an `ngfor` inside `ngfor`?

Comment: Will you put Your data ?

Comment: yes, the value must be printed and updated

Comment: Any error in Console?

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let produto of produtosConfirmadosAnuncio; let r = index">

        <div *ngFor="let variacao of produto.variacao; let m = index">
            <p><strong>Variação {{m+1}}</strong></p>
            <div>
                <div *ngFor="let atributosvariacao of variacao.atributo">
                    <p><strong>{{atributosvariacao.valor_atributo.item_atributo.item}}</strong></p>
                    <p>{{atributosvariacao.valor_atributo.valor}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngFor="let variacao of produto.variacao; let j = index">
            <p><strong>Valor da variação {{j+1}} *</strong></p>
            <input name="valorvariacao{{j}}" required [(ngModel)]="variacao.preco_variacao" type="text">
            <h6 *ngIf="variacao.preco_variacao == null && submited"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i don't know why, but when i discard the name and put [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" the values print correctly, but i don't know why.

Comment: Put your data produtosConfirmadosAnuncio so that we can know exactly what should be printed